# ctx.send() isnt sending the message in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

simple problem: i have this block of code, which should send me  a message on discord from what i know, but it doesnt, i also dont get an error, it just doesnt do anything. it also doesnt stop, but just keep on running to nowhere. the code looks like this:

```
@bot.command
async def steamfetch(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi there")
    if Float <= 0.05:
        print('in bracket')
        element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/span[1]')
        Price = element2.text
        print('ready to send')
        await ctx.send(f"Snipe found:\nMag-7 Carbon Fiber Factory New with Float:\n{Float}\n{Price}") 
bot.run('Token')
```

however, neither the first nor the second message do anything. the variable is definitly smaller than 0.05, but also the first print doesnt come in. i also tried without the if function, and that worked neither. i have a `async def on_ready:` function above, which works, so i assume the bot isnt the problem
any ideas?

Comment: It's simply `@bot.command()` not `@bot.command`

Answer (score -1):

I think that you forgot to put a prefix for your command:

```
client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '.')
```

You can replace `.` with something else

Also try replacing `@bot.command` with `@client.command()`

Like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command()
async def steamfetch(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi there")
    if Float <= 0.05:
    print('in bracket')
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/span[1]')
    Price = element2.text
    print('ready to send')
    await ctx.send(f"Snipe found:\nMag-7 Carbon Fiber Factory New with Float:\n{Float}\n{Price}")
client.run('token')
```

Comment: bot.command nor client.command are better, but client.command is the newest library of discord.py but ultimately, they should both have the same perks.